# Special Character codes to Normal symbol - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

I have a dropdown showing list of languages,
Now, some of these languages contains special HTML characters, but I want to show the real values of those characters.

Like.
`&egrave` should be replaced with `è`

How to do this using Javascript ?

Thanks in advance !!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since it's in HTML, they should visually show up as their correct characters without you needing to do anything…!? `è` and `&egrave;` are the same thing for all intents and purposes in HTML…

Comment: @deceze, yes I totally agree, but its not showing the correct value, there must be a way to enforce this.

Comment: Are we looking at the HTML raw source there, or the DOM inspector? Is your actual raw HTML `&amp;egrave;`? If so… why?!

Comment: @deceze, It is DOM inspector. HTML was supposed decode this by itself, dont know what went wrong (added the SS of my dropdown)

Comment: List comes from a simple JSON file..                                       


"yo": {
      "localized": "Yoruba",
      "name": "&egrave;d&egrave; Yor&ugrave;b&aacute;",
      "en": "Yoruba"
    },
    "fr-be": {
      "localized": "French",
      "name": "Fran\u00e7ais de Belgique",
      "en": "French"
    }

Comment: Oooookay… Why does your JSON contain HTML-encoded data? Not a good start. And if it *does* contain HTML encoded data, you need to set that using `option.innerHTML = name`, not using `option.innerText`… And *that* can lead to HTML injection… So, your data shouldn't be HTML-encoded, period.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```
const decodeHtml = (html) => {
  const t = document.createElement("textarea");
  t.innerHTML = html;
  return t.value;
}
```